# How to estimate uncertainty in Markov chain simulations

Tags: r, probability, simulation, uncertainty

Consider how I fit a Markov chain to my data with R:

```
library(markovchain)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

#Data
A<-structure(c("sunny", "sunny", "sunny", "sunny", "sunny", "sunny", 
"rain", "cloudy", "rain", "cloudy", "sunny", "cloudy", "cloudy", 
"cloudy", "cloudy", "sunny", "sunny", "sunny", "sunny", "rain", 
"sunny", "rain", "sunny", "sunny", "rain", "cloudy", "rain", 
"sunny", "sunny", "cloudy", "rain", "cloudy", "rain", "sunny", 
"rain", "rain", "rain", "sunny", "cloudy", "cloudy", "cloudy", 
"cloudy", "cloudy", "cloudy", "sunny", "cloudy", "rain", "rain", 
"cloudy", "cloudy", "sunny", "sunny", "cloudy", "cloudy", "cloudy"
), .Dim = c(5L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("time1", "time2", 
"time3", "time4", "time5", "time6", "time7", "time8", "time9", 
"time10", "time11")))

#estimate transition matrix
B<-markovchainFit(data=A,name="weather")
mcWeather<-B$estimate

##### Do the forecasting over time and find uncertainty due to small sampling size

KKK<-list()
for(j in 1:10000){
LL<-list()
for(i in 1:5){
  LL[[i]]<-data.frame(cat=rmarkovchain(n = 10, object = mcWeather, t0 = "sunny",include.t0 = TRUE),index=i,time=1:11)  
}

LLL<-rbindlist(LL)
KKK[[j]]<-LLL %>% group_by(time,cat) %>% summarize(freq=n()/i)

KKK[[j]]$perm=j
}

KOO<-rbindlist(KKK)

KKX<-KOO %>% group_by(time,cat) %>% summarize(mean=mean(freq),lq=quantile(freq,0.025),up=quantile(freq,0.975))

# Plot results
ggplot(KKX,aes(x=time,y=mean,color=cat))+geom_line()+ geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lq, ymax=up),color="grey",alpha=0.3)+facet_wrap(~cat)
```

Some more detail to the code: I have 5 individuals that show a sequence of states over time, which can be expressed as a Markov chain.

I fit a Markov chain model to my data to obtain my transition matrix. With this I can now forecast the expected probabilities or expected distribution of my states over time. E.g., via:

```
W0<-t(as.matrix(c("cloudy"=0,"rainy"=0,"sunny"=1))) #start category sunny
for (time in 1:10){
W0 * (B$estimate ^ time)
}
```

But if I repeated my experiment with another 5 individuals I would not necessarily observe my expected distribution of the states over time, because this can be seen as 5 random draws of my Markov chain. These are not enough samples to hit the expected distribution perfectly. With this simulation I try to account for that by 10000 times draw sequences for 5 individuals and calculate the uncertainty of the distribution of my states over time. With this I can account for the uncertainty due to small sampling size (low number of individuals) and better compare different experiments all based on 5 individuals.

So with this code I have to some extent accounted for uncertainty of the small sampling size of 5. (See how confidence increases when changing to `for(i in 1:5000){..` right? Or is this way wrong already?)

Now my question is: Does my estimated transition matrix—the one I used for the simulation above—not already have some uncertainty? Each entry of the transition matrix is estimated from very few observations (sequences of 5 individuals) as well. I saw the function markovchainFit() includes confidence interval estimates for the matrix entries, but I don't know how to link and combine this to the uncertainty estimation I already have done, so that in the end I get a 'global' estimation of the uncertainty in the forecast including (1) the uncertainty in the probability estimates of the transition matrix I fitted to my data and (2) the uncertainty I simulate above due to small sample size.

Comment: What quantity is it whose uncertainty you wish to estimate?

Comment: thanks for your help. The quantity is the uncertainty of the estimated values in my transition matrix. This matrix is fitted for data with the markovchainFit() function. But these values are estimates and have uncertainty (see B$$standardError). I want to account for this uncertainty, because this transition matrix is used then to simulate the uncertainty due to sample size in my code. Does this help? e.g. the mean that I plot in the last line would be different when I  use slightly different values in my transition matrix B. because the B$estimate is only an estimation with uncertainty.

Comment: You haven't addressed the point: you refer to "simulate the uncertainty due to sample size," but what is the uncertainty *of?*  What is your code intended to estimate?

Comment: Sry- There are 2 sources of uncertainty in a random draw of a marcov chain sequence. 1 is based on the probabilities in my transition matrix. These probabilities are estimates for real data so each value has its uncertainty and could be expressed e.g. by a CI. This is the one I asked for in my Q. The other source is the number of random samples I take from my transition matrix to create my sequences and to use for forecasting over time. An infinite number of samples would on average lead to the exact values I expect due to my transition matrix, but a low number (see code) has high uncertainty.

Comment: The source of the uncertainties is clear.  What isn't at all clear is what you are doing with them.  What exactly are you forecasting and how are you doing it? Could you describe it in English or mathematical notation without requiring readers to understand or run your code?

Comment: I added a paragraph in the question. Please tell me if this made it a little clearer and thanks again for your patience!

Comment: Welcome to CV, MriRo!

Comment: Thanks! -such a useful platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) the uncertainty in the probability estimates of the transition matrix I fitted to my data and (2) the uncertainty I simulate above due to small sample size.

(1) I believe `markovchainFit` assumes that the parameters of estimated transition matrix follows normal distribution. Because the returned confidence intervals match the values of `mean +- 1.96 * SE`. Where 1.96 is the critical value for normal distribution at 95% confidence level.

```
# upper CI provided by the model 
B$upperEndpointMatrix
#        cloudy    rain   sunny
#cloudy 0.67698 0.60005 0.52126
#rain   1.00000 0.49190 0.36706
#sunny  0.56847 0.41684 0.78315

# calculated as for normal distribution
B$estimate@transitionMatrix + 1.96 * B$standardError
#        cloudy    rain   sunny
#cloudy 0.67698 0.60006 0.52126
#rain   1.04182 0.49191 0.36707
#sunny  0.56847 0.41684 0.78316
```

**EDIT**

> As you pointed out, to sample individual entries of the transition matrix independently from normal distribution is problematic as row sums can be larger than one.

To stochastically generate a transition matrix, we can use `bootstrap` method provided in `markovchainFit`.

```
B <- markovchainFit(data=c(A[1,], NA, A[2,], NA, A[3,], NA, A[4,], NA, A[5,]),
                 name="weather",
                 method='bootstrap',
                 nboot=1000) #number of models generated

#Check the row sums are indeed 1s
rowSums(B$bootStrapSamples[[1]])
#cloudy   rain  sunny 
#     1      1      1
```

(2) The uncertainty due to small sample size could be viewed as [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with small sample size `n`. In your example, the expected distribution for "sunny" at step 10 with 5 observation is `B(n=5, p=0.30408) / 5`.

```
W0 * (B$estimate ^ 10) # prob of sunny at step 10
#  cloudy    rain   sunny
# 0.42746 0.26846 0.30408
```

The mean of `B(n, p)/n` is `p`, and the variance is `p(1-p)/n`. As `n` becomes larger, the variance reduces.

So, to simulate with both (1) and (2) uncertainties, we may first sample a transition matrix from bootstrapping <s>normal distribution with `mean` and `SE` provided by the model</s>. And followed by your method for random Markov chain sampling.

```
for(j in 1:10000){
LL<-list()
for(i in 1:5){
  mcWeather2 <- mcWeather
  #mcWeather2@transitionMatrix <- mcWeather2@transitionMatrix + 
  #                               rnorm(9, sd=B$standardError) # add parameter uncertainty
  #mcWeather2@transitionMatrix[mcWeather2@transitionMatrix>1] = 1
  #mcWeather2@transitionMatrix[mcWeather2@transitionMatrix<0] = 0

  #EDIT: using bootstrap method for parameter uncertainty
  mcWeather2@transitionMatrix <- B$bootStrapSamples[[sample(length(B$bootStrapSamples), 1)]]
  
  LL[[i]]<-data.frame(cat=rmarkovchain(n = 10, object = mcWeather2, t0 = "sunny",include.t0 = TRUE),index=i,time=1:11)  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like this, but I think it is not 100% robust that way right? When we simply add the deviation to each entry of the transition matrix as you do with rnorm() we totally undermine the fact that entries in this matrix are correlated to each other. This also means that with the rnorm() the row sums can be larger than one. Although it will work practically it makes this solution a little bit imprecise from a theoretical perspective, right?

Comment: You are right. I was totally carried away by the reported confidence intervals, which are probably not meant for sampling purposes.
Another option is to bootstrap from the sequence matrix `A` to generate random model. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thats great thanks a lot.